# Find corresponding lines where search date is between

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with this relevant structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE "beneficiaries" (
"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement
);

CREATE TABLE "beneficiary_dates" (
"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement,
"opening_date" datetime null,
"closing_date" datetime null,
"beneficiary_id" integer not null,
foreign key("beneficiary_id") references "beneficiaries"("id")
)

INSERT INTO "beneficiary_dates" VALUES (1,'2020-02-01 15:08:28','2020-02-05 19:21:51',1);
INSERT INTO "beneficiary_dates" VALUES (2,'2020-04-01 15:08:28',NULL,2);
INSERT INTO "beneficiary_dates" VALUES (3,'2020-04-01 15:08:28','2020-04-29 19:21:51',3);
INSERT INTO "beneficiary_dates" VALUES (4,'2020-06-01 15:08:28',NULL,4);
```

I'm creating a search filter in frontend where the user can pass

- Start search date
- End search date

Now I'm trying to retrieve the beneficiaries that where opened between start and end date.
An opened beneficiary is a beneficiary that match a period (opening_date -- closing_date) where start and end search date are in.

For example:

- Start search date = 2020-01-01
- End search date = 2020-05-01

Lines in beneficiary_dates

```
1 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-05 | 1
2 | 2020-04-01 | null | 2
3 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-29 | 3
4 | 2020-06-01 | null | 4
```

The SQL request has to return lines 1-2-3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic to handle overlapping dates with null should check startdate of one of the period should be inside other period.

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, opening_date, closing_date, beneficiary_date
  FROM beneficiary_dates
 WHERE (opening_date BETWEEN date '2020-01-01' AND date '2020-05-01')
    OR ( date '2020-01-01' >= opening_date
         And ( date '2020-01-01' <= closing_date or closing_date is null )
       )
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work correctly!

Comment: What does date do (and I can't help feeling that this is a little verbose)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data and desired output it can be something like

```
DECLARE @InOpeningDate DATE='2020-01-01';
DECLARE @InClosingDate DATE='2020-05-01';

WITH BENEFICIARY_DATES(ID,OPENING_DATE,CLOSING_DATE,BENEFICIARY_ID) AS 
 ( 
   SELECT 1, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-05' , 1
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 , '2020-04-01', null ,2
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, '2020-04-01' ,'2020-04-29', 3
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 , '2020-06-01' , null , 4
)
SELECT B.ID,B.OPENING_DATE,B.CLOSING_DATE,B.BENEFICIARY_ID
   FROM BENEFICIARY_DATES AS B
    WHERE B.OPENING_DATE BETWEEN @InOpeningDate AND @InClosingDate
     AND ISNULL(B.CLOSING_DATE,@InClosingDate)<=@InClosingDate
```

I also suggest you to use something like '9999-12-31' instead of NULL for the column CloseDate

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't set it to other than NULL if the beneficiary isn't closed. Data is used elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score -1):

"retrieve the beneficiaries that where opened between start and end date":

```
SELECT id, opening_date, closing_date, beneficiary_date
FROM beneficiary_dates
WHERE opening_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-01'
```